# MVC dynamic dropdown list not working,getting error "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'LocID'.'"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to bind the dropownlist values from a database by using the below code, but it throwing error in view. I did the multiple exercises but couldn't reach the output. Can someone please help me with this?

Error:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'LocID'.'

Action Code:

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    List<Location> listObj = new List<Location>();
    {
        listObj = LocDrpDwnList();
    };
    List<SelectListItem> LocList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach(var item in listObj)
    {
        LocList.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = item.LocationName.ToString(),
            Value = Convert.ToInt32(item.LocID).ToString()
        }) ;
    }

    ViewBag.LocID = LocList;
    return View();
}
```

Method to get the List Values from Database:

```
public List<Location> LocDrpDwnList()
{
    SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(conn);
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Location";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, db);
    db.Open();
    List<Location> loclist = new List<Location>();
    using (IDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            Location obj = new Location();
            if (dataReader["LocID"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                if (dataReader["LocID"] != DBNull.Value) { obj.LocID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["LocID"]); }
                if (dataReader["LocationName"] != DBNull.Value) { obj.LocationName =               (string)dataReader["LocationName"]; }
                loclist.Add(obj);
            }
        }
        return loclist;
    }
}
```

View for the Dropdown Control:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LocID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LocID , "Select Location", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: how are you returning model.locID? is it being set in Action? also, what model your view is using? could you show us (relevant portion of) view page also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify your controller action as:

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    List<Location> listObj = LocDrpDwnList();
    /*
     // Doesn't hurt populating SelectListItem this way. But you don't need to do this here. 
    List<SelectListItem> LocList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var item in listObj)
    {
        LocList.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = item.LocationName.ToString(),
            Value = Convert.ToInt32(item.LocID).ToString()
        });
    }
    */
    ViewBag.LocID = (string?)null; //Set to some predefined locId selection, so when page is loaded, dropdown will be defaulted to this value.
    ViewBag.LocList = LocList;

    return View();
}
```

and then update your view as:

```
@{
    var LocList = new SelectList(ViewBag.LocList, "Id", "Text");
    string LocId = ViewBag.LocId ?? (string)null;
}

@Html.DropDownList(@LocId, @LocList , "Select Location", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Instead of using ViewBags, its good practice to use ViewModels like something below:

```
public class AddViewModel
{
    public AddViewModel()
    {
        this.LocList = new List<LocationViewModel>();
    }

    public int? LocId { get; set; }
    // Instead of LocationViewModel, you can go with your idea List<SelectListItem> and change controller action and view accordingly.
    public List<LocationViewModel> LocList { get; set; }
}

public class LocationViewModel
{
    public int LocId { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
```

and your controller action will be:

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    List<Location> listObj = LocDrpDwnList();

    List<LocationViewModel> LocList = new List<LocationViewModel>();

    foreach (var item in listObj)
    {
        LocList.Add(new LocationViewModel
        {
            LocationName = item.LocationName.ToString(),
            LocId  = Convert.ToInt32(item.LocID).ToString()
        });
    }
/*
    ViewBag.LocID = (string?)null; //Set to some predefined locId selection, so when page is loaded, dropdown will be defaulted to this value.
    ViewBag.LocList = LocList;*/

    return View(new AddViewModel{LocList = LocList});
}
```

and your view will be;

```
@using AddViewModel
@Html.DropDownList(m => m.LocId, new SelectList(Model.@LocList, "Id", "Text") , "Select Location", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to create a entry in a Database after selecting a Value from a DROP DOWN LIST, If i'm not wrong your mentioned code of a Controller is not having the POST header, you have to create another Controller with the same name with {HttpPost} hearder.

Kindly find the below link for your reference, may be you will find any sort of help.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551547/asp-mvc-model-entity-validation-does-not-displaying-required-error
```